# Android - highlight icon with SlidingTabLayout

Tags: android, icons, highlight

Currently I'm trying to implement the SlidingTab with icon as tabtitle, then the icon should be highlighted when the corresponding tab is selected.

I use Google's SlidingTabLayout in following tutorial, and have made the icon instead of the tabtitle as well. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WSaSNX5QI-E

I know where I can get the current tab position by implementing OnPageChangeListener, but I don't what should I add in public void onPageSelected(int position) {}
here is my current status and code, please kindly advise, it will be appreciate if you keep the instruction as detail as possible, since I am a very beginner as a android developer.

thanks

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
// Declaring Your View and Variables
private Toolbar toolbar;
private ViewPager mPager;
private SlidingTabLayout mTabs;
private ViewPagerAdapter mAdapter;
private static Context context;
int brightIcons[]={R.drawable.abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00012,R.drawable.abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00012,R.drawable.abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00012,R.drawable.abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00012,R.drawable.abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00012,};



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), getApplicationContext());
    mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mTabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    mTabs.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
    mTabs.setCustomTabView(R.layout.custom_tab_view, R.id.tabText);

    mTabs.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
        @Override
        public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
            return getResources().getColor(R.color.tabsScrollColor);
        }
    });

    mTabs.setViewPager(mPager);

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

}

@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    Toast.makeText(this, Integer.toString(position), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

}
```

}

ViewPagerAdapter.java

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
int NumbOfTabs = 4; // Store the number of tabs, this will also be passed when the ViewPagerAdapter is created
String[]tabs;
CharSequence Titles[]={"P","M","C","S","I"};
int icons[]={R.drawable.profile,R.drawable.match,R.drawable.chat,R.drawable.ic_search,R.drawable.info};
Context context;


public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context mContext) {
    super(fm);
    this.context= mContext;
    tabs = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tabs);

}


@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    switch (position){

        case 0:
            Profile Profile = new Profile();
            return Profile;
        case 1:
            MatchPage MatchPage = new MatchPage();
            return MatchPage;
        case 2:
            Chat Chat = new Chat();
            return Chat;
        case 3:
            SearchPreference SearchPreference = new SearchPreference();
            return SearchPreference;
        case 4:
            Info Info = new Info();
            return Info;
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    Drawable drawable=context.getResources().getDrawable(icons[position]);
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0,100,100);
    ImageSpan imageSpan = new ImageSpan(drawable);
    SpannableString spannableString =new SpannableString(" ");
    spannableString.setSpan(imageSpan,0,spannableString.length(),spannableString.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    return spannableString;

    //return Titles[position];

}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return NumbOfTabs;
}
```

}